# Error getting local system prompt with psexec

Tags: windows-7, psexec

I'm trying to get a local system prompt with psexec using the command:

```
psexec -i -s CMD
```

I get the following error:

```
Error establishing communication with PsExec service on LAB
The network path was not found.
```

Please forgive my ignorance, I'm new at this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please check your **TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service**, it must be running or set to manual startup.

**Note:**

if you don't set,  error when disabled: "The network path was not found."

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Try to run with **System32** (it has the highest permissions).

[image]

Comment: There must be something fundamental in Windows that I don't understand: Running the command from `C:\windows\system32` *did* make it work. Why does the folder where I run the command from make a difference?